# Eclipse won't run c++ projects

Tags: c++, eclipse

In my CSCI class, we are coding in Eclipse. Throughout the semester, I have had no trouble with the program (other than figuring out how to use it). However, it won't allow me to run my current project. I click run, and it says it launches, but nothing appears in the console, and it says the program is terminated. As I was trying to find a solution, I was trying to run projects from earlier in the semester, but none of them will run now either-they all just launch and terminate.

What can I do to try to fix this? Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe recreating the project with a new one and copying the code? It's the easiest way to avoid any strange setting (aside from hunting them). It's likely the debug configuration has something wrong with it and you could also delete it to see if creating a fresh one helps.